# Deploying to a different heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, git, heroku

As advised here, in rails 3.1 I should use cedar instead of bamboo.

I did

```
heroku create --stack:cedar
```

and now I want to deploy only to that.

When I do

```
git push heroku
```

It deploys to the old app (bamboo stack)

How do I force deployment to the new app (and new address as well)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your git remote heroku is linked to the old stack app.

First do a `git remote rm heroku`

then do a `git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:your-appname-cedar-stack.git`